# Why people talk about the FIVE pillars of the AWS framework when the documentation says SIX?

Tags: amazon-web-services, frameworks, cloud

I'm currently preparing my AWS Cloud Practitioner certification exam. The one on pluralsight named ["AWS Certified Cloud Practitioner: Exam Prep"](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/aws-cloud-practitioner-exam-prep/exercise-files)  which was las updated 13 march 2023 by David Tucker. He says many times the five pillars of the AWS Framework. But looking online, and the official documentation of AWS says ["SIX pillars"](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/apn/the-6-pillars-of-the-aws-well-architected-framework/)

Thanks in advance

Looking at the documentation and was expecting and history but didn't find much nor on google

Answer (score 3):

AWS [added](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/sustainability-pillar-well-architected-framework/) a sixth pillar in late 2021 - Sustainability:

> The discipline of sustainability addresses the long-term environmental, economic, and societal impact of your business activities. You can find prescriptive guidance on implementation in the Sustainability Pillar [framework](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/wellarchitected/latest/sustainability-pillar/sustainability-pillar.html).

The material you're looking at must pre-date that announcement.